# AndroidStudio 2.2.1 won't recognize my Android device

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, usb

This is totally weird. Running an old openSuse sytem.  Everything was working just fine and dandy until I installed the latest AndroidStudio upgrade to 2.2.1.  And now, all of the sudden, the Linux system no longer recognizes by device when I connect it with a USB cable.

Tried restarting computer and restarting device.  Cable and device work fine when connect to another computer.  But not another port on this computer. Another USB cable and device are recognized on this USB port.

The device recognizes that it is connected to the computer, and goes into USB debugging mode as it should.  But the computer does not respond at all.  lsusb does not display the device.  dmesg does show some interesting errors.

```
[ 4418.029098] usb 3-14: new high-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[ 4418.196304] usb 3-14: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[ 4418.196309] usb 3-14: can't read configurations, error -71
[ 4418.349402] usb 3-14: new high-speed USB device number 34 using xhci_hcd
[ 4418.516380] usb 3-14: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[ 4418.516393] usb 3-14: can't read configurations, error -71
[ 4418.669676] usb 3-14: new high-speed USB device number 35 using xhci_hcd
[ 4418.682737] usb 3-14: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[ 4418.682739] usb 3-14: can't read configurations, error -71
[ 4418.835808] usb 3-14: new high-speed USB device number 36 using xhci_hcd
[ 4418.848993] usb 3-14: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/all
[ 4418.849007] usb 3-14: can't read configurations, error -71
[ 4418.849065] usb usb3-port14: unable to enumerate USB device
```

It is hard to see how installing the AndroidStudio upgrade would affect things that appear to be happening at the kernel level.  But the timing is really suspicious.  There was, maybe 20 minutes between when it was working fine and when it was not.  And the only thing even remotely suspicious that happened in that time frame with the Android Studio upgrade.

Comment: did you try reinstalling the driver for the device? my lg sometimes do that

also try revoking the debug mode and then reenable it

Comment: several restarts (both pc and android device) and disable/enable developer mode fixed for me :/